# Episerver-Set content area using scheduled job

Tags: episerver

I have an existing property in episerver that is now changed to a content area.This is basically for storing image that the content area will be used with just 1content item. I'll be adding a validation check for 1item of image of type .png for instance.

Now because this is an existing property with a different type,i need to create a schedule job to set the value.
So the question is Can we set content area property with a schedule job?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ContentAreaItem` instance with its `ContentLink` property set to an `IContent` instance of type `ImageData` to programmatically add an image to the `Items` property of a `ContentArea`.